# Add Prev/Next buttons in multiple items array in AngularJS (ngRepeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a multiple items slider to list some players using ng-repeat (Angular 1.6). I'd like to add a prev/next buttons in the ul>lis to access the next or previous player in the array, shifting the view item by item.

HTML----**sliderdemo.html**

```
<div ng-controller="SliderDemoCtrl">
   <div class="champions-slider">
            <ul class="team-members list-inline text-center" style="display:flex" >
                <li ng-repeat="player in players | limitTo: 4" style="padding:10px"> 
                    <div class="img-holder">
                        <a href="/player/{{ player.name }}"><img ng-src="{{ player.image }}" alt="{{player.name}}" width="20px"></a>
                    </div>
                    <strong class="name">{{ player.name }}</strong>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="btn-prev" ng-click="?????">Prev</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn-next"ng-click="?????">Next</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller js---**slider.demo.controller.js**

```
 var myApp = angular.module('slider.demo', []);
 myApp.controller('SliderDemoCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
 $scope.players = [
   {
    image:"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1",
    name: "tes 1"
   },
   {
    image:"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=2",
    name: "tes 2"
   },
   {
    image: "http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=3",
    name: "tes 3"
   },
   {
    image:"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=4",
    name: "tes 4"
   },
   {
    image:"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=5",
    name: "tes 5"
   },
   {
    image: "http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=3",
    name: "tes 6"
   }
  ];
}]);
```

Here is a plunkr of the question: https://plnkr.co/edit/J7dxeMfM22ju5gpZl5ri?p=preview

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thx!

Comment: an easy solution that won't need too much code change would be to display another array in your `ng-repeat`. This 2nd array would be filled with the first 4 elements at start, and you can assign functions in your `ng-click` so that you add and remove elements on this array, filling it with values from the total array. EDIT: since angular 1.4, seems you can also use a start value `limitTo:length:start`

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://plnkr.co/edit/hAE6o0rUx0Jzm4MmRzLZ?p=preview or you want it to be circular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are searching like below solution :

```js
// Code goes here

var myApp = angular.module('slider.demo', []);
myApp.controller('SliderDemoCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.players = [
      {
        image:"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1",
        name: "tes 1"
      },
      {
        image:"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=2",
        name: "tes 2"
      },
      {
        image: "http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=3",
        name: "tes 3"
      },
      {
        image:"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=4",
        name: "tes 4"
      },
      {
        image:"http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=5",
        name: "tes 5"
      },
      {
        image: "http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=3",
        name: "tes 6"
      },
    ];
    $scope.size=0;
    $scope.next=function(){
      if($scope.size+4==$scope.players.length)
        return;
       $scope.size+=1;
      
    }
    $scope.prev=function(){
      if($scope.size==0)
       $scope.size=0;
      else 
       $scope.size-=1;
      
    }
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="slider.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="SliderDemoCtrl">
  <div class="champions-slider">
    <ul class="team-members list-inline text-center" style="display:flex" >
     <li ng-repeat="player in players | limitTo: 4" style="padding:10px"> 
      <div class="img-holder">
       <a href="/player/{{ players[$index+size].name }}"><img ng-src="{{ players[$index+val].image }}" alt="{{players[$index+val].name}}" width="20px"></a>
      </div>
      <strong class="name">{{ players[$index+size].name }}</strong>
     </li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="btn-prev" ng-click="prev()">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn-next"ng-click="next()">Next</a>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the pagination by ng-if using a $index.Just go through [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XUGl3FH5S5Svrxpb12yw?p=preview)

```
    $scope.pre = 0;
    $scope.nex = 4;

    $scope.nextItem  = function(){
      $scope.pre = $scope.nex;
      $scope.nex = $scope.nex + 4;
    }

    $scope.prevItem  = function(){
      $scope.nex = $scope.pre
      $scope.pre = $scope.pre - 4;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to move one by one, not for 4 by 4. Thx anyway!

Comment: @user1499369 updated the code. kindly see the plunker once again

Comment: thx but I don't want to see any items disappear. I want 4 items always in the view, but iterating one by one. Thanks anyway!